# Java Swing Library

Tags: java, swing

I have implemented a library which makes Java Swing programming easier. I am just posting the library. There is a program that uses this library to implement examples of many Swing components but I cannot include that program here because the total size will become more than the allowed limit of 65K characters. I will the examples program in another question.

Can someone please do the code review.

The code is below:

---

### SwingLibrary.java

```
class SwingLibrary {

    // if width is 0 then the frame is maximized horizontally
    // if height is 0 then the frame is maximized vertically
    public static JFrame setupJFrameAndGet(String title, int width, int height) {
        int state = 0;
        JFrame tmpJF = new JFrame(title);
        if (width == 0) {
            state = state | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_HORIZ;
        }
        if (height == 0) {
            state = state | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_VERT;
        }
        if ((width != 0) || (height != 0)) {
            tmpJF.setSize(width, height);
        }
        tmpJF.setExtendedState(tmpJF.getExtendedState() | state);
        tmpJF.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        tmpJF.setLayout(null);
        tmpJF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        return tmpJF;
    } // end of setupJFrameAndGet

    // width and height are the preferred width and height of JPanel
    public static ArrayList<Object> setupScrollableJFrameAndGetFrameAndPanel(String title, int width, int height) {
        JFrame tmpJF = new JFrame(title);
        tmpJF.setExtendedState(tmpJF.getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        tmpJF.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //tmpJF.setLayout(null);

        JPanel tmpJP = new JPanel();
        //tmpJP.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width + 1000, height + 1000);
        tmpJP.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        tmpJP.setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane tmpJSPFrame = new JScrollPane(tmpJP, JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS, JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        tmpJSPFrame.getHorizontalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);
        tmpJSPFrame.getVerticalScrollBar().setUnitIncrement(10);
        tmpJF.add(tmpJSPFrame);

        ArrayList<Object> tmpA = new ArrayList<>();
        tmpA.add((Object) (tmpJF));
        tmpA.add((Object) (tmpJP));

        return tmpA;
    } // end of setupScrollableJFrameAndGetFrameAndPanel

    // actLisObj: object which implements action listener
    public static JButton setupJButtonAndGet(String text, Object actLisObj, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JButton tmpJB = new JButton(text);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJB.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        tmpJB.addActionListener((ActionListener) actLisObj);
        return tmpJB;
    } // end of setupJButtonAndGet

    // halign: horizontal alignment of text, valign: vertical alignment of text
    public static JLabel setupJLabelAndGet(String text, boolean opaque, Color bg, int halign, int valign, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JLabel tmpJL = new JLabel(text);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJL.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        tmpJL.setOpaque(opaque);
        if (bg != null) {
            tmpJL.setBackground(bg);
        }
        tmpJL.setHorizontalAlignment(halign);
        tmpJL.setVerticalAlignment(valign);
        return tmpJL;
    } // end of setupJlabelAndGet

    public static JTextField setupJTextFieldAndGet(int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JTextField tmpJTF = new JTextField();
        tmpJTF.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        return tmpJTF;
    } // end of setupJTextFieldAndGet

    public static JFormattedTextField setupJFormattedTextFieldAndGet(Format fmt, Object initialVal, Object propertyChangeLis, String propertyToListenFor, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JFormattedTextField tmpJFTF = new JFormattedTextField(fmt);
        tmpJFTF.setValue(initialVal);
        tmpJFTF.addPropertyChangeListener(propertyToListenFor, (PropertyChangeListener) propertyChangeLis);
        tmpJFTF.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        return tmpJFTF;
    } // end of setupJFormattedTextFieldAndGet

    // itemLisObj: object which implements item listener
    public static JCheckBox setupJCheckBoxAndGet(String text, boolean state, Object itemLisObj, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JCheckBox tmpJCB = new JCheckBox(text, state);
        tmpJCB.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        tmpJCB.addItemListener((ItemListener) itemLisObj);
        return tmpJCB;
    } // end of setupJCheckBoxAndGet

    // actLisObj: object which implements action listener
    public static JRadioButton setupJRadioButtonAndGet(String text, boolean state, Object actLisObj, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JRadioButton tmpJRB = new JRadioButton(text, state);
        tmpJRB.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        tmpJRB.addActionListener((ActionListener) actLisObj);
        return tmpJRB;
    } // end of setupJRadioButtonAndGet

    public static ButtonGroup setupButtonGroupAndGet() {
        ButtonGroup tmpBG = new ButtonGroup();
        return tmpBG;
    } // end of setupButtonGroupAndGet

    public static JPasswordField setupJPasswordFieldAndGet(int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JPasswordField tmpJPF = new JPasswordField();
        tmpJPF.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        return tmpJPF;
    } // end of setupJPasswordFieldAndGet

    public static JTextArea setupJTextAreaAndGet(String text, int rows, int columns, boolean setEditableFlag, boolean setLineWrapFlag, boolean setWrapStyleWordFlag, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JTextArea tmpJTA = new JTextArea(text, rows, columns);
        tmpJTA.setEditable(setEditableFlag);
        tmpJTA.setLineWrap(setLineWrapFlag);
        tmpJTA.setWrapStyleWord(setWrapStyleWordFlag);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJTA.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        return tmpJTA;
    } // end of setupJTextAreaAndGet

    public static JScrollPane setupScrollableJTextAreaAndGet(JTextArea jta, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JScrollPane tmpJSP = new JScrollPane(jta);
        tmpJSP.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        return tmpJSP;
    } // end of setupScrollableJTextAreaAndGet

    public static JList<String> setupJListAndGet(ListModel<String> lm, int selectionMode, int visibleRowCount, int initialSelectedIndex, Object listSelLisObj, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JList<String> tmpJList = new JList<String>(lm);
        tmpJList.setSelectionMode(selectionMode);
        tmpJList.setVisibleRowCount(visibleRowCount);
        if (initialSelectedIndex >= 0) {
            tmpJList.setSelectedIndex(initialSelectedIndex);
        }
        tmpJList.addListSelectionListener((ListSelectionListener) listSelLisObj);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJList.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        return tmpJList;
    } // end of setupJListAndGet

    public static JScrollPane setupScrollableJListAndGet(JList jlist, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JScrollPane tmpJSP = new JScrollPane(jlist);
        tmpJSP.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        return tmpJSP;
    } // end of setupScrollableJListAndGet

    public static JComboBox<String> setupJComboBoxAndGet(ComboBoxModel<String> cbm, int initialSelectedIndex, Object actLisObj, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JComboBox<String> tmpJComboBox = new JComboBox<String>(cbm);
        if (initialSelectedIndex >= 0) {
            tmpJComboBox.setSelectedIndex(initialSelectedIndex);
        }
        tmpJComboBox.addActionListener((ActionListener) actLisObj);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJComboBox.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        return tmpJComboBox;
    } // end of setupJComboBoxAndGet

    public static JProgressBar setupJProgressBarAndGet(int orientation, int min, int max, int initialVal, boolean borderPaintedFlag, boolean stringPaintedFlag, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JProgressBar tmpJPB = new JProgressBar(orientation, min, max);
        tmpJPB.setValue(initialVal);
        tmpJPB.setBorderPainted(borderPaintedFlag);
        tmpJPB.setStringPainted(stringPaintedFlag);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJPB.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        return tmpJPB;
    } // end of setupJProgressBarAndGet

    public static JSlider setupJSliderAndGet(int orientation, int min, int max, int initialVal, int minorTickSpacing, int majorTickSpacing, boolean paintTicksFlag, boolean paintLabelsFlag, Object changeLisObj, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JSlider tmpJS = new JSlider(orientation, min, max, initialVal);
        tmpJS.setMinorTickSpacing(minorTickSpacing);
        tmpJS.setMajorTickSpacing(majorTickSpacing);
        tmpJS.setPaintTicks(paintTicksFlag);
        tmpJS.setPaintLabels(paintLabelsFlag);
        tmpJS.addChangeListener((ChangeListener) changeLisObj);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJS.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        return tmpJS;
    } // end of setupJSliderAndGet

    public static JTree setupJTreeAndGet(DefaultMutableTreeNode rootNode, int selectionMode, Object treeSelLisObj, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JTree tmpJTree = new JTree(rootNode);
        tmpJTree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(selectionMode);
        tmpJTree.addTreeSelectionListener((TreeSelectionListener) treeSelLisObj);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJTree.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        return tmpJTree;
    } // end of setupJTreeAndGet

    public static JScrollPane setupScrollableJTreeAndGet(JTree jtree, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JScrollPane tmpJSP = new JScrollPane(jtree);
        tmpJSP.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        return tmpJSP;
    } // end of setupScrollableJTreeAndGet

    public static JSpinner setupJSpinnerAndGet(SpinnerModel sm, boolean editableFlag, Object spinnerChangeLisObj, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JSpinner tmpJSPN = new JSpinner(sm);
        tmpJSPN.addChangeListener((ChangeListener) spinnerChangeLisObj);
        if (editableFlag == false) {
            JComponent editor = tmpJSPN.getEditor();
            if (editor instanceof JSpinner.DefaultEditor) {
                ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) editor).getTextField().setEditable(editableFlag);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: Could not set editableFlag for JSpinner.");
            }
        }
        tmpJSPN.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        return tmpJSPN;
    } // end of setupJSpinnerAndGet

    public static JColorChooser setupJColorChooserAndGet(Color initialColor, boolean borderTitleFlag, String borderTitle, Object colorChooserChangeLisObj, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JColorChooser tmpJCC = new JColorChooser(initialColor);
        tmpJCC.getSelectionModel().addChangeListener((ChangeListener) colorChooserChangeLisObj);
        if (borderTitleFlag == true) {
            tmpJCC.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(borderTitle));
        }
        tmpJCC.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        return tmpJCC;
    } // end of setupJColorChooserAndGet

    public static JDialog setupJDialogAndGet(Frame owner, String title, boolean modal, int width, int height) {
        JDialog tmpJD = new JDialog(owner, title, modal);
        tmpJD.setSize(width, height);
        tmpJD.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        tmpJD.setLayout(null);
        tmpJD.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        return tmpJD;
    } // end of setupJDialogAndGet

    public static ArrayList<Object> setupScrollableJDialogAndGetDialogAndPanel(Frame owner, String title, boolean modal, int dialogWidth, int dialogHeight, int panelWidth, int panelHeight) {
        JDialog tmpJD = new JDialog(owner, title, modal);
        tmpJD.setSize(dialogWidth, dialogHeight);
        tmpJD.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        tmpJD.setLayout(null);
        tmpJD.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel tmpJP = new JPanel();
        tmpJP.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(panelWidth, panelHeight));
        tmpJP.setLayout(null);

        ScrollPane sp = new ScrollPane(ScrollPane.SCROLLBARS_ALWAYS);
        sp.getHAdjustable().setUnitIncrement(10);
        sp.getVAdjustable().setUnitIncrement(10);
        sp.add(tmpJP);
        tmpJD.getRootPane().setContentPane(sp);

        ArrayList<Object> tmpA = new ArrayList<>();
        tmpA.add((Object) (tmpJD));
        tmpA.add((Object) (tmpJP));

        return tmpA;
    } // end of setupScrollableJDialogAndGetDialogAndPanel

    public static JToggleButton setupJToggleButtonAndGet(String text, Object itemLisObj, boolean opaque, Color bgcolor, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JToggleButton tmpJTB = new JToggleButton(text);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJTB.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        tmpJTB.addItemListener((ItemListener) itemLisObj);
        tmpJTB.setOpaque(opaque);
        tmpJTB.setBackground(bgcolor);
        return tmpJTB;
    } // end of setupJToggleButtonAndGet

    public static JSeparator setupJSeparatorAndGet(int orientation, Color bgcolor, boolean setBoundsFlag, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height) {
        JSeparator tmpJS = new JSeparator(orientation);
        tmpJS.setBackground(bgcolor);
        if (setBoundsFlag == true) {
            tmpJS.setBounds(xpos, ypos, width, height);
        }
        return tmpJS;
    } // end of setupJSeparatorAndGet

    public static JMenuBar setupJMenuBarAndGet(Color fgcolor, Color bgcolor) {
        JMenuBar tmpJMB = new JMenuBar();
        tmpJMB.setOpaque(true);
        tmpJMB.setForeground(fgcolor);
        tmpJMB.setBackground(bgcolor);
        return tmpJMB;
    } // end of setupJMenuBarAndGet

    public static JMenu setupJMenuAndGet(String text, Color fgcolor, Color bgcolor) {
        JMenu tmpJM = new JMenu(text);
        tmpJM.setOpaque(true);
        tmpJM.setForeground(fgcolor);
        tmpJM.setBackground(bgcolor);
        return tmpJM;
    } // end of setupJMenuAndGet

    public static JMenuItem setupJMenuItemAndGet(String text, Object actLisObj, KeyStroke k, Color fgcolor, Color bgcolor) {
        JMenuItem tmpJMI = new JMenuItem(text);
        tmpJMI.setOpaque(true);
        tmpJMI.setForeground(fgcolor);
        tmpJMI.setBackground(bgcolor);
        tmpJMI.setAccelerator(k);
        if (actLisObj != null) {
            tmpJMI.addActionListener((ActionListener) actLisObj);
        }
        return tmpJMI;
    } // end of setupJMenuItemAndGet

} // end of SwingLibrary
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of code here, so here's a few things to get started with...

### Comments

- Consider JavaDoc for function description comments that the clients of your library might want to know, such as `// if width is 0 then the frame is maximized horizontally`. There's a good chance that their IDE will pick them up and give them hints when they're calling your functions.
- Don't leave commented out code laying around.  Use source control. When you're done with code `//tmpJF.setLayout(null);`, delete it.
- Do end section comments like `// end of setupJTextAreaAndGet` really add value, or do they just add noise to your code? For me, if a braced section of code is long enough that it would need a comment, it's usually an indication that the logic within it needs to be broken up a bit more.

### Arguments

> ```
> public static JSlider setupJSliderAndGet(int orientation, 
>     int min, 
>     int max, 
>     int initialVal,
>     int minorTickSpacing, 
>     int majorTickSpacing, 
>     boolean paintTicksFlag, 
>     boolean paintLabelsFlag, 
>     Object changeLisObj, 
>     boolean setBoundsFlag, 
>     int xpos, 
>     int ypos, 
>     int width, 
>     int height) {
> ```

The `setupJSliderAndGet` has 14 arguments. That's a lot. To use the method, I'd be relying on my IDE to tell me what value to pass where, based on the argument name / javadoc. Do you always need to pass all of these arguments? It seems like, if `setBoundsFlag` is `false`, then the last 4 arguments are ignored. This doesn't seem easier to use. Would it be better two methods, one that sets it up with the bounds and one that doesn't? This removes arguments and simplifies the individual implementations. The x,y,width,height combo exists on other methods. Is this a type waiting to be discovered?